# centos 7 do not show login screen, startx fails with "xauth: file /home/user/.serverauth.xxxx does not exist"

Tags: nvidia, centos7

For some unknown reasons, my NVIDIA driver does not work after installing caffe (I might do "yum update" during caffe installation).

So I re-installed NVIDIA driver, it works properly. But Centos 7 does not show login screen after reboot. The X sever is running, the default is graphical.target.

I also tried to "startx" or "sudo startx", and both shows "xauth: file /home/user/.serverauth.xxxx does not exist"

Is there any suggestion for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? I think you meant to post this on Super User or Server Fault, though you're probably going to need to provide a lot more specific details before they can help you even there.

Comment: I did not say it is related to programming. I used nvidia and centos7 as flags. I saw people ask such questions in stackoverflow. Am I in the wrong place?

Comment: _"I did not say it is related to programming"_ Actually, you did, by posting it on this programming Q&A. _"I saw people ask such questions in stackoverflow."_ Where? _"Am I in the wrong place?"_ Yes :)